# Case When Like in Eloquent in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i'm new with eloquent laravel

curently i have working mysql query below to transform data

```
select * from `dsa_data_realisasi_resolver` where (CASE WHEN akun LIKE '%51%' THEN 51 ELSE 0 END ) and year(`tanggal`) = 2020 and `kdsatker` = 412772 group by `akun`
```

when i try to use eloquent with something like this

```
 $realisasi=Realisasi::whereRaw('(CASE WHEN akun LIKE '%51%' THEN 51 ELSE 0 END )')
                        ->whereYear('tanggal','2020')
                        ->where('kdsatker','412772')
                        ->groupby('akun')
                        ->get();
                        dd($realisasi);
```

there are errors

```
ErrorException
A non-numeric value encountered
```

when i try to remove single quotes '

```
$realisasi=Realisasi::whereRaw('(CASE WHEN akun LIKE %51% THEN 51 ELSE 0 END )')
                            ->whereYear('tanggal','2020')
                            ->where('kdsatker','412772')
                            ->groupby('akun')
                            ->get();
                            dd($realisasi);
```

the errors are

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%51% THEN 51 ELSE 0 END ) and year(`tanggal`) = ? and `kdsatker` = ? group by `a' at line 1 (SQL: select * from `dsa_data_realisasi_resolver` where (CASE WHEN akun LIKE %51% THEN 51 ELSE 0 END ) and year(`tanggal`) = 2020 and `kdsatker` = 412772 group by `akun`)
```

is there any solution with eloquent for query with **case when like '%data%'**

Thanks

Comment: Try with `"(CASE WHEN akun LIKE '%51%' THEN 51 ELSE 0 END )"` -> double quote to contain where raw statement. And to send dynamic you can try `"(CASE WHEN akun LIKE '%".data."%' THEN 51 ELSE 0 END )"`

Comment: Glad I could help. Posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `"(CASE WHEN akun LIKE '%51%' THEN 51 ELSE 0 END )"` Notice the double quote to contain the `whereRaw` statement.

And to send dynamic data you can try `"(CASE WHEN akun LIKE '%".data."%' THEN 51 ELSE 0 END )"`

So your query should look like this:

```
$realisasi=Realisasi::whereRaw("(CASE WHEN akun LIKE '%".$data."%' THEN 51 ELSE 0 END )')
                    ->whereYear('tanggal','2020')
                    ->where('kdsatker','412772')
                    ->groupby('akun')
                     ->get();
```

MySQL requires the like pattern to be inside single quotes. For more reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/pattern-matching.html